# Backend definition in multiple VCL files in Varnish 5

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I'm setting up a Varnish 5 instance connected to 2 backend servers (Magento 2 applications).

I'm using the new Varnish 5 feature of loading multiple VCL files. To keep things very simple for now, I'm going to use 1 backend server in my example.

So, I have a `magento.vcl` defined as follows:

```
vcl 4.0;

import std;

# The minimal Varnish version is 4.0
# For SSL offloading, pass the following header in your proxy server or load balancer: 'X-Forwarded-Proto: https'

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8088";
}

include "/etc/varnish/common.vcl";
```

And a `top.vcl`

```
vcl 4.0;

import std;

backend default { .host = "127.0.0.1"; }

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.host == "magento2.dev") {
        return (vcl(magento_vcl));
    }
}
```

Then I run

```
service varnish restart
varnishadm
vcl.load magento /etc/varnish/conf.d/magento.vcl
vcl.label magento_vcl magento 
vcl.load top /etc/varnish/top.vcl
vcl.use top
quit
```

When I browse to magento2.dev, I get a backend fetch error after some seconds. It's only when I go in `magento.vcl` and change the name of the backend and make a backend hint that it works. See below:

```
vcl 4.0;

import std;

# The minimal Varnish version is 4.0
# For SSL offloading, pass the following header in your proxy server or load balancer: 'X-Forwarded-Proto: https'

backend magento {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8088";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    set req.backend_hint = magento;
}

include "/etc/varnish/common.vcl";
```

Why should I be specifying a backend hint? Shouldn't Varnish be loading a different VCL according to the host specified in top.vcl? Or is there something wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

It seems varnish does load the vcl that you specifed via the vcl(label). That .vcl should specify the backend_hint that's valid for the particular backend the .vcl is for. I don't think there's anything wrong.